# How to pass data-index attribute to the index of photoswipe js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, photoswipe

In reference to photoswipe js : http://photoswipe.com/documentation/getting-started.html

I'm having trouble passing the data-index attribute to the index of photoswipe.

HTML:

```
    <td>
        <div class="picture" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">
            <figure style="display:initial;" itemprop="associatedMedia" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
                <a class="picture" href="images/AN241_02.jpg" itemprop="contentUrl" data-size="2000x1200" data-index="0" data-title="AN241 02 55">
                    <img class="lazy thumbnail " data-original="image_cache/AN241_02-cache.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail" alt="Image description" src="image_cache/AN241_02-cache.jpg" style="display: inline;">
                </a>
            <figcaption itemprop="caption description">description</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
    </td>
```

JS:

```
var onThumbnailsClick = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;

    var eTarget = e.target || e.srcElement;

    // find root element of slide
    var clickedListItem = closest(eTarget, function(el) {
        return (el.tagName && el.tagName.toUpperCase() === 'FIGURE');
    });

    });

    if(!clickedListItem) {
        return;
    }

    // find index of clicked item by looping through all child nodes
    // alternatively, you may define index via data- attribute <---HOW?

    var clickedGallery = clickedListItem.parentNode,
        childNodes = clickedListItem.parentNode.childNodes,
        numChildNodes = childNodes.length,
        nodeIndex = 0,
        index;

    for (var i = 0; i < numChildNodes; i++) {
        if(childNodes[i].nodeType !== 1) { 
            continue; 
        }

        if(childNodes[i] === clickedListItem) {
            index = nodeIndex;
            break;
        }
        nodeIndex++;
    }


    if(index >= 0) {
        // open PhotoSwipe if valid index found
        openPhotoSwipe( index, clickedGallery );
    }
    return false;
};
```

You can see above that the "data-index" attribute is located in the "a" tag and I would like to pass this to the index in the JS.

Apologies as I'm not familiar with JS and would appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to get data-index, you have to get value of this attribute from your clicked element before last "If" statement, then pass it to openPhotoSwipe init function :)

```
var newIndex = parseInt(eTarget.parentNode.getAttribute("data-index"));

if(newIndex >= 0) {
    // open PhotoSwipe if valid index found
    openPhotoSwipe( newIndex, clickedGallery );
}
```